# How to update the comment of my post in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a big issue about updating the comment of a post. The thing is the client don't want it to be public so default is no show. I have this code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getPost } from '../../actions/post';

// Other parts
import ScrollToTop from '../routing/ScrollToTop';

const CommentEdition = ({ getPost, post: { post, loading }, match }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    cstatus: false,
    comment: '',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getPost(match.params.id);
  }, [getPost, match.params.id]);

  const { cstatus, comment } = formData;

  const onChange = (e) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  return (
    <section className='section-size-2 lighter-bg'>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='grid'>
          <div className='column-4 '>
            <Link
              to='/user-comments'
              className='white-button'
              style={{ marginBottom: 30, display: 'block' }}
            >
              Back to Comments
            </Link>
            <h4>Comments management</h4>
            <h1 className='animated-text'>Review & Edit</h1>
          </div>
          <div className='column-8 profile-main-area'>
            <Fragment>
              <form className='box white shadow text-left'>
                <label>Did you become a client already? *</label>
                <div className='form-input-select'>
                  <select
                    id='cstatus'
                    name='cstatus'
                    value={cstatus}
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                  >
                    <option value='true'>Yes</option>>
                    <option value='false'>No</option>
                  </select>
                  <i className='fas fa-chevron-down'></i>
                </div>

                <label>About You</label>
                <textarea
                  name='comment'
                  placeholder='Tell us about you'
                  value={comment}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                ></textarea>

                <button className='button' type='submit'>
                  Submit
                </button>
              </form>
            </Fragment>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

CommentEdition.propTypes = {
  getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  post: state.post,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPost })(CommentEdition);
```

It comes from clicking on the specific comment I want to publish, but I don't have any idea how I would put the info in the form. I have `getPost(match.params.id)` and is showing the right post, but how can I get the that specific comment and populate in the form for update.

The link looks like this `http://localhost:3000/review-commment/5e806b4d6de9c747939a1696/5e9f4ff01c70d30300c42feb`

Thanks for your help, if this is too complicated and need more details please let me know.

I'm attaching an image so you can see how the two comments are loading in the state.

[image: Screenshot of how it looks]

NEW SCREENSHOT
[image: with changes from Han]

CODE UPDATED AND NEW SCREENSHOT:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getPost } from '../../actions/post';

// Other parts
import ScrollToTop from '../routing/ScrollToTop';

const CommentEdition = ({ getPost, post: { post, loading }, match }) => {
  const [formData, setFormdata] = useState({
    cstatus: false,
    comment: ''
  });

  const { comments } = useSelector(state => ({ ...state.post.post }));

  const curco =
    comments && comments.filter(el => el._id === match.params.commentid);

  console.log(curco);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPost(match.params.id);
  }, [getPost, match.params.id]);

  const { cstatus, comment } = formData;

  const onChange = e =>
    setFormdata({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  return (
    <section className="section-size-2 lighter-bg">
      <ScrollToTop />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="grid">
          <div className="column-4 ">
            <Link
              to="/user-comments"
              className="white-button"
              style={{ marginBottom: 30, display: 'block' }}
            >
              Back to Comments
            </Link>
            <h4>Comments management</h4>
            <h1 className="animated-text">Review & Edit</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="column-8 profile-main-area">
            <Fragment>
              <form className="box white shadow text-left">
                <label>Comment Status *</label>
                <div className="form-input-select">
                  <select
                    id="cstatus"
                    name="cstatus"
                    value={cstatus}
                    onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  >
                    <option value="true">Published</option>>
                    <option value="false">Draft</option>
                  </select>
                  <i className="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </div>

                <label>Comment</label>
                <textarea
                  name="comment"
                  placeholder="Comment goes here"
                  value={comment}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                ></textarea>

                <button className="button" type="submit">
                  Submit
                </button>
              </form>
            </Fragment>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

CommentEdition.propTypes = {
  getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post,
  curco: state.curco
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPost })(CommentEdition);
```

I wanted to add the code from where these comments are coming, maybe that could help better.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const CommentItem = ({ auth, post: { _id, title, comments, date } }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {auth.user.usertype === 'worker' && comments.length > 0 ? (
        <div
          className="quotee-post comment-list"
          style={{
            borderBottom: '2px solid #e6e6e6',
            paddingBottom: 25,
            marginBottom: 25
          }}
        >
          <Fragment>
            <div className="title">List of comments for</div>
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            {comments.map((comment, id) => (
              <div key={id} className="caption comments-data">
                <div className="first-col">
                  <h6>{comment.comment}</h6>

                  <Fragment>
                    <div className="sub">By {comment.name}</div>

                    <p>
                      Date <Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{comment.date}</Moment>
                    </p>
                  </Fragment>
                </div>
                <div className="second-col">
                  {comment.cstatus ? (
                    <Fragment>
                      <small>
                        Comment Status:
                        <br />
                        <span style={{ color: '#28a745' }}>
                          <i className="fas fa-check"></i> published
                        </span>
                      </small>
                    </Fragment>
                  ) : (
                    <Fragment>
                      <small>
                        Comment Status:
                        <br />
                        <span style={{ color: '#fe9100' }}>
                          <i className="fas fa-pause-circle"></i> draft
                        </span>
                      </small>
                    </Fragment>
                  )}
                  <br />
                  <Link
                    className="red-button"
                    to={`/review-commment/${_id}/${comment._id}`}
                  >
                    Review and Edit
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Fragment>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

CommentItem.propTypes = {
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(CommentItem);
```

Screenshot showing the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been a little busy, but here's is the solution to this issue. The actual solution was really cleaner, what I did is just load the info here

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getPost, updateComment } from '../../actions/post';

// Other parts
import ScrollToTop from '../routing/ScrollToTop';

const CommentEdition = ({
  getPost,
  post: { post, loading },
  location: { currentcom },
  postId,
  commentId,
  updateComment,
  match
}) => {
  const [formData, setFormdata] = useState({
    cstatus: false,
    comment: '',
    user: '',
    name: '',
    photo: ''
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getPost(match.params.id);

    const newcstatus = currentcom && currentcom.cstatus;
    const newcomment = currentcom && currentcom.comment;
    const newuser = currentcom && currentcom.user;
    const newphoto = currentcom && currentcom.photo;
    const newname = currentcom && currentcom.name;

    setFormdata({
      cstatus: newcstatus,
      comment: newcomment,
      user: newuser,
      photo: newphoto,
      name: newname
    });
  }, [getPost, currentcom, match.params.id]);

  const { cstatus, comment, user, photo, name } = formData;

  const onChange = e =>
    setFormdata({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    postId = match.params.id;
    commentId = match.params.commentid;
    updateComment(postId, commentId, formData);
  };

  return (
    <section className="section-size-2 lighter-bg">
      <ScrollToTop />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="grid">
          <div className="column-4 ">
            <Link
              to="/user-comments"
              className="white-button"
              style={{ marginBottom: 30, display: 'block' }}
            >
              Back to Comments
            </Link>
            <h4>Comments management</h4>
            <h1 className="animated-text">Review & Edit</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="column-8 profile-main-area">
            <Fragment>
              <form
                onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}
                className="box white shadow text-left"
              >
                <label>Comment Status *</label>
                <div className="form-input-select">
                  <select
                    id="cstatus"
                    name="cstatus"
                    value={cstatus}
                    onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  >
                    <option value="true">Published</option>>
                    <option value="false">Draft</option>
                  </select>
                  <i className="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </div>

                <label>Comment</label>
                <textarea
                  name="comment"
                  placeholder="Comment goes here"
                  value={comment}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                ></textarea>

                <label>Author of comment</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" value={name} readOnly />

                <label>User</label>
                <input name="user" type="text" value={user} readOnly />

                <label>Photo file</label>
                <input name="photo" type="text" value={photo} readOnly />

                <button className="button" type="submit">
                  Submit
                </button>
              </form>
            </Fragment>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

CommentEdition.propTypes = {
  getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  updateComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPost, updateComment })(
  CommentEdition
);
```

What really makes it easier is that from the other component I loaded the props onto this one, then this one it turns to be just a regular form mounting the data from props, but when I save I had to splice that comment.

```
<Link
     className="red-button"
     to={{
       pathname: `/review-commment/${_id}/${comment._id}`,
       currentcom: comment
     }}
     >
     Review and Edit
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the comment a list of object from store using `useSelector`
You can add the following code to get a list of comment object and start filtering with id to get the specific comment

```
const comment = useSelector(state => state.post.comments)
// I can see that state are not parent of comments, you might want to add the parent in above like 
// useSelector(state => state.posts.comments)
// In this case, posts is the parent of comments

const filteredComment = comment && comment.filter(el => el._id === match.params.id)
// filteredComment.comment should be the comment you needed
```

Updated answer:

```
        <textarea
          name="comment"
          placeholder="Comment goes here"
          initialValue = {curco ? curco[0].comment || undefined}
          value={comment}
          onChange={e => onChange(e)}
        ></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Han, it didn't work. I got TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in the first line. Maybe I place it in the wrong place, but I don't know much about this function. I put it right after and outside useEffect.

Comment: yea, you should replace the state.comments with the object and keys. I didn't know whats the object name as u only ss half of it.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I did, I wrote state.post.comments

Comment: Are you running a older version of React? Have a look in this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14484

Comment: Alright, I’ll take a look. I mean, I have other projects and all I learned is hook and don’t have other issues, but I will take your suggestion.

Comment: Hey Han, so I realized that the problem is that I called the useSelector on React instead react-redux, but now I'm getting this error `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: great, do u mind update the post with a screenshot of the useSelector variable return? In my answer would be `comment`. The possible cause is that u are not refering to the correct state in Store.

Comment: Hey Han, I added the new screenshot.

Comment: As your screenshot, state.post are having no post which doesnt have comments. which cause the filter to return error. I have updated the comment. You need to ensure the `useSelector`(which means the `state.post.comment`) is not null/undefined to get the filtered comment.

Comment: Ok, but in the original code I posted I had `getPost(match.parama.id)` and the the post was in the state, when I added your code I realized is not there, so I don’t think that’s the issue, there should be something else, or should I need to get rid of the useEffect?

Comment: `useSelector` doesnt change the store state. it just pull the data from `store` you might wanna check your useEffect or reducer/action.

Comment: Hey Han, I realized what is the problem, it is not hat I wasn't populating correctly. I console log post I see the post, but when I console log comment it says is undefined. `{_id: "5e806b4d6de9c747939a1696", featuredimg: "plitzcorporation.png", …}
comments: (2) [{…}, {…}]
date: "2020-03-29T09:33:01.653Z"
featuredimg: "plitzcorporation.png"
likes: (2) [{…}, {…}]
name: "Norman"
photo: "android-chrome-512x512.png"`

Comment: you must make sure you point to the correct state to return an object. Have a read https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

Comment: Hey Han, can I send what I have so far. I would like to pay you for the help because I need this fixed urgently. I can update the post here and a screenshot. Let me know if you have time to help me with this.

Comment: Hey Han, thanks for you help, I updated the code, as you can see I made some modifications to your code and I was able to console.log the curco. I added the code from where I'm displaying all the comments. You will find it in `<Link
                    className="red-button"
                    to={`/review-commment/${_id}/${comment._id}`}
                  >
                    Review and Edit
                  </Link>`

Comment: Thanks! I hope you find the solution!

Comment: Hey Hans, don’t worry. I did it! So happy man. I will publish the answer later today. Thanks for your help though.